# CMake Error: CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES must be non-empty if set

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I'm using CMake 3.26 to configure a project using CUDA. Its `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(foo CUDA)
```

and I'm directing it to a specific CUDA version, by invoking

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER=/usr/local/cuda-12.2/bin/nvcc
```

and I'm getting:

```
CMake Error at /path/to/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:277 (message):
  CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES must be non-empty if set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To see what's actually happening, try to "arbitrarily" set `CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`, like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "native")
project(foo CUDA)
```

Now, you'll get a different error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  The CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER:

    /usr/local/cuda-12.2/bin/nvcc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
```

and this is the actual problem. Unfortunately, it is not detected and reported as such, and what you get is a complaint about how CMake was not able to populate its `CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` variable using its auto-detection logic.

The solution is: Don't direct CMake to a nonexistent nvcc... you probably got the path wrong or forgot to install that version etc.

---

Edit: I've filed a bug about this with Kitware: [bug 25709](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25709)